# SQL Server 2008 R2 - save query results as a SQL statement readable by phpmyadmin?

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

I am working with a database in SQL Server 2008 and I want to export the query results as a SQL statement with the basic format:

```
CREATE TALBE TableName(columns here) 
INSERT INTO TableName (columns here) VALUES (values here)
```

Now, I know I can export these as a CSV file, however, the issue is that some columns have double quotes in their entries. This presents a problem because if I import this CSV file to phpMyAdmin, using double quotes to identify columns will give me extra or will make me lose columns.

Is there a way to export my query results straight to an SQL File?

Or is there a way to export my query results to CSV in such a way that my columns are enclosed in `|`?

Answer (score 1):

In SSMS right click on your table

Script Table as ==> INSERT TO ==> File

To get the INERT INTO from table result:

Use the [free SSMS Tools Pack addin](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Features?f=8) which has "Generate Insert statements from resultsets, tables or database" feature

Comment: Can you do this for the query result table?

Comment: Also you can make a SELECT INTO and insert your data into a new table and then use the above way from SSMS  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp

Comment: The SSMS Tools Pack Addon seems to generate a different query? I'm looking for something like: `INSERT INTO Table1 (id, name, address, phone) VALUES (id1, name1, address1, phone1), (id2, name2, address2, phone2)...(idN, nameN, addressN, phoneN).` The screenshot in the Tools Pack Addon looks different.

Comment: Right click on the result set and choose Script Grid Results

Comment: It's free for 2005 and 2008 but not for 2012

Answer (score 0):

In Microsoft Sql Server Management Studio(MSSMS) right click on your table.

[image]

Comment: Can you do this for the query result table?